# how to allow 0 in foreign keys constraint in mysql?

Tags: mysql, null, foreign-keys, primary-key, zero

Let's suppose I have a following table:

```
UID int (11) not null,  FOREIGN KEY (UID) REFERENCES users(ID),
OID int (11),  FOREIGN KEY (OID) REFERENCES orders(ID),
primary key(UID,OID)
```

Note the primary key.

And, I wanted to allow to have one `NULL` in order ID (OID) for each user ID (UID).

Though after setting the primary key it automatically makes my OID field `NOT NULL`.

As a work around I'm thinking to store `0` instead to mark it as an unrelated field.

So, now the question, is it possible to allow a foreign key constraint to accept also zeros (0) apart from the `references` of the specified field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNIQUE KEY` constraint can be used in this case:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id int not null, primary key (id));
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1), (2), (3);

CREATE TABLE orders (id int not null, primary key (id));
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (1), (2), (3);

CREATE TABLE users_orders (uid int NOT NULL, oid int DEFAULT NULL,
                 FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES users (id),
                 FOREIGN KEY (oid) REFERENCES orders (id),
                 UNIQUE KEY (uid, oid));

INSERT INTO users_orders (uid) VALUES (1);
```

Here's [a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1540f/3) to play with.

But be aware that you (probably) will still be able to insert more than one combination of `specific UID - NULL` in your table ( I assume here that you use `InnoDB` ). For example, this query...

```
INSERT INTO users_orders o (uid) VALUES (1), (1);
```

... will succeed as well (as it won't break any existing constraints).

If this should be strictly prohibited, you better use some dummy value *both* in `users` and `orders` table as well - to make the `foreign key` constraint in your intersection table usable.

As a sidenote, I admit I'm a bit surprised by this situation. Intersection tables are usually designed so that they don't have any NULLable fields: it's LEFT (or RIGHT) JOIN in query that should be used to include users that don't have any orders, for example. Could you explain a bit why this decision (to make OID nullable) was chosen at first hand?

Comment: The idea is to store billing information. Each user has a default billing info, and it is also stored separately for each order. If you advice some other way of storing it I would gladly follow up...

Comment: Well, what makes you think adding `uid` to `orders` table is not appropriate? ) As each order (I assume) have one and only one user assigned to it. Then it'd be easy to query for all users and their orders (including users without any orders at all by means of `LEFT JOIN`).

Comment: That makes sense. I could store billing info within each order as well. But I wonder where would I store the default billing then?..

Comment: Do not store the whole billing info, it's redundant. Store reference to it instead. As `user - billing info` is obviously in `1-n` relationship, it should be stored within a separate table, that references `users` (via uid) as well.

Comment: Aha I think I understand the idea, so I could just have the orders table with references to billing, where I would have a primary billing ID with an auto_increment. The only question is, how would I then identify which billing entry is a default one?..

Comment: Can default billing entry be changed? For example, user A has two profiles, A1 and A2: A1 was the default at first, but then user decided to make A2 one instead. Can this happen?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16080/discussion-between-raina77ow-and-anonymous)

Comment: it's unlikely to switch back, but he may want to create a new billing entry and specify it as default upon creation.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to have a 'surrogate Primary Key' instead of your current PK and instead put a `UNIQUE` constraint on the following composite (UID,OID) - provided you are open to having a surrogate primary key - like a identity column

Comment: That's a great idea, but wouldn't it affect the performance for not having a primary key, when we make a select based on these fields? Would it require to define indexes manually, or can it be used just like that?

Comment: You will need to create an index on UID, OID but that should take care of your performance concern

Comment: UNIQUE KEY (uid, oid) actually creates a composite index over these two fields.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible in MySQL, but workaround could be to insert an dummy entry with 0 value in referencing foreign table.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I had as a first thought, but that looks like a dirty way, because it actually affects the relations and makes it a related field, whilst ideally it shouldn't have any relations for such field.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UNIQUE KEY. It allows using NULL values.